# Angular2/4: Include third party scripts and styles in .net framework

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am building a new angular 4 application in .net framework which comes with the webpack. Previously when I used the angular cli, I get the angular-cli.json where I could provide the thirdparty scripts and css. In this case I dont have the angular-cli.json. My project structure is as below. 
[image]

My webpack looks like below

[image]

when I tried to add the third party css files to the nonTreeShakableModules, it didn't work.

My index.cshtml and _layout.cshtml that got generated with the app.

My Index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<app>Loading...</app>

@*asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server"*@

<script src="~/dist/vendor.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
@section scripts {
    <script src="~/dist/main-client.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
}
```

My layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - CareTeamPortal</title>
    <base href="~/" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/dist/vendor.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the application have a single stylesheet as `style.css` in the `index.html`.

Add the import statements for the respective stylesheets as below

```
@import url('.................'); // specify the path
```

Comment: updated the question with my index.cshtml and _layout.cshtml that got generated with the app.

Comment: you want to add dynamically?

Comment: No.. I want to add the below styles.. <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="YOUR_PATH/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css" />

Comment: Where should I make that import?

Comment: just to make it clear, I created a new  ASP.NET Core Web Application project and selected the angular template. Everything runs smooth expect I am unable to add third party css.